# No release momentum inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

In my activity, I have two `RecyclerView`s inside a `ScrollView`. The problem is that when I swipe/flick the `ScrollView`, scrolling stops immediately. Is there a way to get the `ScrollView` to implement momentum or inertia so there's some deceleration before the scrolling stops?

My XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/threadload_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/subforums"
        android:name="net.polunom.forum.fragments.ThreadFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragments.ThreadFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_subforum"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/threadlist"
        android:name="net.polunom.forum.fragments.ThreadFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragments.ThreadFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_thread"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out! All I had to do was set `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` to the two `RecyclerView`s, and everything started working like a charm.

Comment: This worked for me. I have my RecyclerView within a CollapsingToolbarLayout, and this worked.

Comment: This worked fro mee too but I have one horizontal recyclerVew (rv) and one vertical rv inside the nestedScrollBar, if I set nestedScrollingEnable to false, the horizontal is very difficult to scroll as you have to move the finger almos perfectly horizontal. Any Idea to scroll the horizontal rv  like it was working before putting nestedScrollingEnable to false?. I've tried all combinations: enable-enable, enable-disable, disable-disable.  enable-enable is easy to scroll horizontally but not smooth scroll, other combinations have smooth scroll but is really difficult to scroll the horizontal rv.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable nested scrolling directly in your XML with: `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`

So your XML would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/threadload_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/subforums"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:name="net.polunom.forum.fragments.ThreadFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragments.ThreadFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_subforum"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/threadlist"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:name="net.polunom.forum.fragments.ThreadFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragments.ThreadFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_thread"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```